# "require" management in Ruby

Tags: ruby, require

Imagine that I use `require` to load a ruby file named ftp_reader.rb, e.g.

```
require './readers/ftp_reader'
```

10 files contain the above `require` statement and make use of this file. Let's say I misclassified ftp_reader and the path should look like this:

```
require './remote_readers/ftp_reader'
```

I would have to remember which 10 files required the ftp_reader, and update the path. This is a pain. I am always renaming and relocating files and folders in an effort to have my project represent the problem domain as closely as possible (BDD).

My question is, is there some gem out there that uses some kind of manifest file which contains the paths of all project files and has a version of the `require` method that makes use of this manifest to locate my dependencies? This file would have aliases to files and I would use the alias in my `require` statement instead of the file path. If anyone has used require.js, this will sound very familiar. Does such a thing already exist in the Ruby world? Or how is this problem tackled in the Ruby world?

Comment: Did you ever think of creating a gem? (maybe that's already the answer)

Comment: am I to create a gem for every file?

Comment: if you are using 10 times the same file, I think all your code is about one topic..so creating a little gem could be a good choice.

Comment: I agree, gem files are useful. But what if I have 15 files in my gem and some reference others? Then I am back where I started. I get that gems are for creating software packages but I am looking for dynamic resolution of script file locations rather than statically referencing script paths all over. I am guessing it's not an native feature of Ruby but I am wondering if the community has solved this problem with some commonly known API. I am new to Ruby

Answer (score 2):

A comment in advance: Your wish (and my answer) has a taste of ugly code. I would recommend to think about one or more gems with your files. More at the end of my answer.

What I did in the past: 
I had also small scripts in different folders and one common file `myscripts.rb`. This `myscripts.rb` was loaded at the beginning of most of my files and set the loading path:

```
require_relative '../myscripts.rb' #
require 'ftp_reader'
```

`myscripts.rb` was defined as:

```
$:.unshift('c:/<..full_path..>/readers/')
$:.unshift('c:/<..full_path..>/writters/')
#... more pathes ...
```

When I changed my folder structure, I need only to change my `myscripts.rb`:

```
$:.unshift('c:/<..full_path..>/remote_readers/')
```

All scripts used now the new folder structure, because my `myscripts.rb` never changed it location.

I used the full path, because relative paths would be relative to the main file, not to `myscripts.rb`.

There would be the possibility to combine `__FILE__` and `expand_path` to use relative pathes to my `myscripts.rb` - but I never used it.

The problem: If I rename my scripts, this does not work (often I kept the old script name and loaded the new one).
And it was not flexible with old versions.

Later I created one gem `mytools` and added all scripts to this gem. If I needed an old version, it was possible to load old version.

Today I create a gem for each concern/topic. It doesn't matter, how many files are in the gem. A gem solves a problem for me. Not the number of files is important, but the [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). A gem contains the scripts to solve a concern, the tests and it is the base for a documentation.

Comment: Your last paragraph has me wondering if i need to rethink my understanding of gems. Until now, I thought of them as packages in a package management system. I never saw gems as a way to structure a project into concerns. Indeed if my app was made of many gems each containing just a handful of files, the require path issue would never grow into an unmanageable mess or a bunch of ugly hacks. But I am always scared to repurpose any tool because I am taking it beyond the bounds of the creators original design requirements. have you run into any problems with ur approach?

Comment: also is it a bad idea to override the require method and implement either a search algorithm for finding scripts or doing a lookup on a global hash of registered script aliases to paths (require.js)?

Comment: You wrote 'I never saw gems as a way to structure a project into concerns.' - neither do I. In your question you wrote '10 files contain the above require' - If the 10 files belong to one project, then I would change the code of the 10 scripts after a move of your ftp_reader.rb (you may look for the old usages with a search in the filesystem). But if the 10 scripts belong to different projects, then they need a common library - and that would be a new gem.

Comment: And another remark: Take a look at [datamapper](https://rubygems.org/gems/datamapper) - The gem is splitted in many sub-gems (`dm-...`). I think thats an example to structure a project into concerns.

Comment: changing the code in the 10 files is exactly what I don't want to ever do. The path to a script should only ever be written once for the entire app or gem and only its alias should be reused; if that's not happening then something is wrong. i'll explore the datamapper project to see if i get some more answers

Answer (score 0):

Most people tackle the problem of dependency management with a bundle manager in Ruby. Bundler is the biggest one, as it's what's included in Rails. You create a Gemfile that specifies all the bundles you want to use, bundler creates its own repository of bundles, and you can just require them as you like. If you do server-side JavaScript, it's very similar to npm.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I am talking about dynamically resolving file locations of scripts rather than static references to them in a require statement. I am not taking about gems which could only apply if you're advising that I create a gem for every script file